# Cleaning up function interposition with dlsym

Tags: c, valgrind, dlsym, resource-cleanup, library-interposition

As a malloc wrapper, I use this classical snippet of code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;
    if (!real_malloc)
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    void *p = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%d) = %p\n", size, p);
    return p;
}
```

Valgrind is upset because there are buffers still allocated by dlsym at the end of the program.

```
==32691== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==32691==    at 0x4C279FC: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==32691==    by 0x528559F: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:142)
==32691==    by 0x5285099: dlsym (dlsym.c:71)
==32691==    by 0x4060BC: malloc (memory.c:222)
```

How can I release those resources ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, and I don't know if it's even possible to release this buffer, but I would just ignore it. The dlsym buffer will be released when the program exits, and you need it as long as the program is running.

Comment: It does not bother me either, I am just curious.

Comment: Ok. Do you call dlclose? Does this buffer still remain?

Comment: I did that, but I only got an assertion failure


`Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 719: _dl_close:assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 blocks are still reachable

These blocks are *just fine*. You don't need to worry about them, they are *not* leaks. There is nothing to see here, move along.

It's the "definitely lost" that you should care about.